# Removing front parts of a String in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm using a python-script to get results from a calculation-programm into a format i can use for evaluation.
I managed to access the name of my objects and save them as String. The name of the objects is always sth. like this:

```
WN 0897 City A - CityB North - 10 7 km
```

This is one String and I'd like to make it two like this:

```
number = WN 0897
name = CityA - CityB
```

The part with the length of the line isnt necessary for me and can be ignored.
How do I do that in Python?

Ty in Advance

Comment: Does your string always contain `North` word? If not how do you know where name ends?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using  Regular Expressions.

For regular expressions you need to import module `import re`

On following link you can find examples for regular expressions:
[examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)